# If Ubuntu freezes when running off a USB drive, will it freeze after full installation?

Tags: installation, usb-drive, freeze

I'm planning to install Ubuntu on an aging Compaq Presario V5000.

I've established that the Unity desktop is not suited to this laptop, and am now using the standard (Gnome?) desktop.

I'm grappling with ndiswrapper and my wireless chipset.

But I'm still running it off a USB drive before I take the plunge and install properly to my internal HD. Part of my reticence in completing the installation is I'm experience freezes after about 10-20 minutes usage. Is this likely to be in any way related to running it off the USB drive?

EDIT: marked answer as accepted, installing onto hard disk has eliminated freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that your freezes are related to running off the USB drive? **Yes**. Is it likely? ***shrug***. You'd have to track down what is causing the freeze. It could be freezing because:

- the usb disk is bottlenecking your throughput.
- the usb disk is dying.
- network manager misbehaved, causing a kernel panic.
- etc..

Comment: thanks. Do you have any specific advice on how to go about troubleshooting this? eg identifying a kernel panic.